# What is the value of the inradius of triangle $PHQ$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For refrence: The right triangle $ABC$, right at $B$, the height $BH$ is drawn. Let $P$ and $Q$ be the intersections of triangles $AHB$ and $BHC$,
$PQ$ intersects at $E$ the $BH$, where $\frac{BE}{EH} = 5\sqrt2$ and the inradius of the triangle $ABC$ measures $10$.
Calculate the inradius of triangle $PHQ$.(Answer: $1$)

My progress..It is a complicated drawing ..not to scale...

I found it a difficult question and didn't get much out of it.... Maybe there is some relationship between the inradius but I don't know

I I know this(by property): $ r_1+r_2+R = BH\\
r_1+r_2+10 = BH$

Also: $\triangle MPH \sim \triangle NQH \implies\\
\frac{r_1}{r_2} = \frac{PH}{QH}$

By Geogebra $\triangle PQH$ is right?? $\implies$ T.Poncelet: $PH+HQ = PQ+2r$

...

[image]

Comment: PHE=45°, QHE=45°, PHQ=90°

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu  with geogebra yes, but it would be necessary to demonstrate

Comment: $(EH-PM)/PM=(QN-EH)/QN \Rightarrow EH=2PM\cdot QN/(PM+QN)$.

Comment: $HP$ is bisector of right angle, also for $HQ$

Comment: $2r_1=AH+BH-AB$, $2r_2=CH+BH-BC$, $2R=AB+BC-AC$, $2r_1+2r_2+2R=AH+CH+2BH-AH-CH=2BH \Rightarrow r_1+r_2+R=BH$

Comment: $2r_1r_2/(r_1+r_2)=(r_1+r_2+10)/(5\sqrt{2}+1)$

Comment: And of course $r_1^2+r_2^2=10^2$

Comment: Just to confirm, are you sure that it is $5\sqrt2$ and not $5/2$?

Comment: I think you should be able to show it using harmonic range

Comment: @ACB  confirmed $5\sqrt2$..

Comment: @ACB  I didn't understand... wouldn't $BH$ be tangent to the incircle $ABH$ and therefore we would have only one point of contact of the incircle $ABH$ with $BH$, which would be $E$ and not $S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

As $\angle PHQ = 90^\circ$ and $HE$ is its angle bisector, the incenter of $\triangle PHQ$ must lie on the segment $HE$. We mark it as $I$.

Next we note that $PM = MH = r_1$ and $QN = NH = r_2$. That leads to $PH = r_1 \sqrt2, QH = r_2 \sqrt2$.

As $\triangle AHB \sim \triangle BHC$ and they are right triangles, their inradii must be in the ratio of their hypotenuse.

So, $ \displaystyle \frac{r_1}{r_2} = \frac{c}{a} ~ $. But in right triangle $\triangle PHQ$, we also have $ \displaystyle \frac{PH}{HQ} = \frac{r_1}{r_2}$.

So, $\triangle PHQ \sim \triangle ABC \sim \triangle AHB \sim \triangle BHC \implies \angle HPQ = \angle A$.

If $r$ is the inradius of $\triangle PHQ$, $HI = r \sqrt2$

Using similarity of triangles,

$ \displaystyle \frac{AH}{r_1} = \frac{PH}{r} \implies AH = \frac{\sqrt2 r_1^2}{r} $. Similarly, $\displaystyle CH = \frac{\sqrt2 r_2^2}{r}$

Adding, $ \displaystyle AC = \frac{2 (r_1^2 + r_2^2)}{r \sqrt2} = \frac{PQ^2}{r \sqrt2} \implies \frac{AC}{PQ} = \frac{PQ}{r \sqrt2}$

As $\dfrac{AC}{PQ} = \dfrac{10}{r}, PQ = 10 \sqrt2$

$PH + HQ - PQ = 2r \implies \sqrt2 (r_1 + r_2) - 10 \sqrt2 = 2 r$. Using $r_1 + r_2 = BH - 10$, we get $ ~ BH - 20 = \sqrt2 r$.

Given $PI$ is angle bisector of $\angle HPE$ and $\angle BPI = 90^\circ$ so it follows that pencil $P (HE, IB)$ is harmonic. So we have,

$\dfrac{HI}{IE} = \dfrac{HB}{BE}$

$\dfrac{HI}{HE-HI} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{5 \sqrt2}$

$ (10 \sqrt2 + 1) HI  = (5 \sqrt2 + 1) HE = BH$

$(20 + \sqrt2) r = BH = 20 + \sqrt2 r$

$ \implies r = 1$

Comment: A question of "big people"...many concepts involved...there was a doubt at the end, can you explain? $(10\sqrt2+1)HI=(5\sqrt2+1)HE$(ok)= $BH$ Why did it equal $BH$?
$(20+\sqrt2)r??=BH=(20+\sqrt2)r$

Comment: @petaarantes We are given $BE: = 5 \sqrt2 \cdot EH$. Adding $EH$ to both sides, $BH = (5 \sqrt2 + 1) EH$. Also using harmonic range was not really necessary. We can use one more similarity in the last step instead of using harmonic range but I decided to use it.

Comment: Also, $HI = r \sqrt2, BH = 20 + r \sqrt2$ are coming from earlier steps.

Comment: I am eager to know why $\angle BPI=90^\circ$.

Comment: @ACB $\angle HPE = \angle A \implies \angle HPI = \frac12 \angle A$. $\angle ABH = 90^\circ - \angle A, \angle PBH = 45^\circ - \frac12 \angle A$ and $\angle BHP = 45^\circ$. So, $\angle BPH = 90^\circ + \frac12 \angle A$. That leads to $\angle BPI = 90^\circ$

Comment: thanks for the clarification a..now I understand

Answer (score 3):

$S$ the point of touching incircle ABH with BH. $T$ is the point of intersection of straight lines $PS$ and $QN$. Triangles $PES$ and $PQT$ are right and similar. $PS=r_1$, $PT=r_1+r_2$, $QT=r_2-r_1$. From similarity:

$$ES=PS\cdot QT/PT=r_1\frac{r_2-r_1}{r_1+r_2}$$

$$EH=ES+SH=r_1\frac{r_2-r_1}{r_1+r_2}+r_1=\frac{2r_1r_2}{r_1+r_2}$$

From similarity of triangles $AHB$, $CHB$ and $ABC$ and Pythagoras theorem follows $$R^2=r_1^2+r_2^2\Rightarrow 2r_1r_2=(r_1+r_2)^2-R^2\Rightarrow EH=r_1+r_2-\frac{R^2}{r_1+r_2}$$

$$BH=BE+EH=5\sqrt{2}\cdot EH+EH=EH(5\sqrt{2}+1)$$

Also $BH=r_1+r_2+R$, then

$$r_1+r_2+R=\left(r_1+r_2-\frac{R^2}{r_1+r_2}\right)(5\sqrt{2}+1)$$

Let $r_1+r_2=xR$, then

$$x+1=\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)(5\sqrt{2}+1)\Rightarrow x=(x-1)(5\sqrt{2}+1)\Rightarrow x=1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{10}$$

The incircle radius of tectangular triangle $PHQ$ is $$\frac{PH+HQ-PQ}{2}=\frac{r_1\sqrt{2}+r_2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2r_1^2+2r_2^2}}{2}=R\sqrt{2}\ \frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{R}{10}=1$$

The answer will transform to 2 if one changes $5\sqrt{2}$ to $\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Excellent...gratitude...probablymetn there was a printing error in the template...one of the alternatives would be 1 so your resolution is correct

Comment: "$S$ the point of touching incircle ABH with $BH$".Could you clarify? Could you clarify?  Wouldn't E be this point?

Comment: @ACB The foor of perp is touching point of incircle, because P is center of incircle